# Qt C++ video libraries

Tags: c++, qt

I'm looking for a video library for Qt 4 (C++/Windows) that has:

**1) Basic video playback functionality**

It should play all the common video formats such as DVD VOB and MP4/MKV/AVI (h264, xvid, divx). It should also be able to deinterlace the video automatically and display it in Display Aspect Ratio.

**2) Cropping**

It should have some basic functionality to remove black bars (user supplied arguments).

**3) Snapshots**

It should have functionality to take snapshots in memory.

**4) Frame-by-frame seeking**

It should have some basic functionality to do frame-by-frame seeking, e.g. prevFrame(), nextFrame(), jumpTo(frame) and getNumFrames().

---

I have tried the following and from what I could find the functionality they support:

**Qt Phonon:**

1. Yes. Plays all the needed formats and displays them correctly.
2. No.
3. No. Not implemented (returns empty image).
4. No.

**QtFFmpegWrapper:**

1. Partial. Does not deinterlace DVD VOBs. Does not display DVD VOBs in DAR.
2. No.
3. Yes.
4. Partial. Broken for MKV (h264).

**Qt VLC:**

1. Yes. Plays all the needed formats and displays them correctly.
2. Yes. Have not tried if it works though.
3. Partial. Only to disk. **edit:** QPixmap::grabWindow(player->videoWidget()->winId()) works.
4. No. Only by milliseconds.

Now I'm looking at QVision, which seems to have all of those features except for cropping. Maybe implementing cropping isn't that difficult. But I'm wondering if there's any other libraries I should look into? Or perhaps I missed something and they're possible with one of these libraries. Thanks.

Comment: a frame doesn't really exists in compressed video. Computing from milliseconds offset will be really easy, when *you* assign a frame rate.

Comment: @CapelliC *"a frame doesn't really exist in compressed video"* **if** the method uses inter-frame compression, instead of just [intra-frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intra-frame)

Comment: 'Frame-by-frame seeking' especially prevFrame() is not possible for all the video sequences. It is fine for all-intra frames (I frames), but it is hard or impossible for P or B frames in most libraries (the dependencies of frames). ( unless you make you own cache yourself. but there will be the memory size problem if cache is too big)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [Movie Player Gold SDK ActiveX 3.6](http://www.viscomsoft.com/products/movieplayergold/index.html) from ViscomSoft. I don't see cropping mentioned on their site but memory snapshots and frame-by-frame steps are among supported features.

I used their VideoEdit and Screen2Video SDKs in Windows Qt software, worked quite well.